# How to type 0/(zero slash)?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to type zero slash on my HP laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 installed on it?

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.4 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
```

How to do this?

Comment: This is a very strange question, since the obvious answer is `press the zero button and then whatever modifier-key + button that produces a forward slash in your keyboard layout`. Obviously you are having issues wit this, perhaps you can give us some more details about what kind of issues you are having?

Comment: In `bash`or in a GUI application as `gedit`or `chrome`?

Comment: @jcbermu yes gedit.

Comment: By "zero slash" are you asking about the Latin-1 symbol \216 (zero with a slash through it, html entity &#216;)?

Comment: -1 you should describe what is happening when you try it, and even include a screenshot of what is happening,. Your title is very poor as it really doesn't state your difficulty at all. Like asking "how do I cross the road" and not stating what problem you are having doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Copy paste this:

> Ø - capital
>
> ø - lower case

---

**Solution 2**

Don't know about Ubuntu, but on Window you can use:

`Alt`+`0216` for Ø

`Alt`+`0248` for ø

Numbers have to be entered on the num pad.

---

**Solution 3**

Change keyboard layout to Norwegian and hit `:` (assuming your keyboard layout is US/UK)

Comment: Just noticed that you said zero slash and not o slash.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98, this is Unicode character 216, or D8 in hexadecimal, so you can type it on Ubuntu by pressing ctrl-shift-u to enter a unicode character, typing D8, and then enter.